# How to assign value to several numbers of string?

Tags: java, string

I have c1,c2,c3,c4... etc
Every c has value of 2 letter string, for example AX or BY or CZ
then I split that string so I have cArray with array of 2 strings.
My question is how to change string value into integer value for A or B or C, so I can use it for any number of c, without using if statement for every c

```
String c1 = args[0];
String c2 = args[1];
String[] c1Array = c1.split("(?!^)");
String[] c2Array = c2.split("(?!^)");
int total = c1Array[0] + c2Array[0];
```

for example I want A has value 1, B has value 2, C has value 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Map`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_map_interface.htm)

```
    String cArray[]={"AX","BY","CZ"};
    Map<String, Integer> map=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("A", 1);
    map.put("B", 2);
    map.put("C", 3);
    String[] c1Array = cArray[0].split("(?!^)");//Will give you A
    String[] c2Array = cArray[1].split("(?!^)");//Will give you B
    int total = map.get(c1Array[0]) +  map.get(c2Array[0]);
    System.out.println(total);//Output: 3
```

Comment: thank you, maybe this is what I need, but I'm not sure about <String, Integer> do I need to assign String and Integer? or is it just regex?

do I need to import another library? because my eclipse doesn't recognize map and hashmap cannot be resolved into a type

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a Map here. Something like

```
Map<Character, Integer> charValue = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

and then you need to put all the charter-value combination in this map.

```
charValue.put('A', 1);
charValue.put('B', 1);
```

Then, once you are done inputting all these values in your map, in order to fetch them

```
System.out.println(charValue.get('A'));
System.out.println(c1Array[0]);    //in your case
```

Also,

```
charValue.put('A', 1);     //and
charValue.put('a', 1);     //two different things
```

Comment: thank you, maybe this is what I need, but I'm not sure about <Character, Integer> do I need to assign Character and Integer? or is it just regex?

do I need to import another library? because my eclipse doesn't recognize map and hashmap cannot be resolved into a type

Comment: both of you have correct answer, you are faster but sorry I said it is String, anyway thanks, I'm not allow to give upvote yet